# Show xml on webview as Chrome does

Tags: java, xml, javafx, webview

I want to show the full xml document, including tags.
I tried this:

```
//The variable f refers to the xml file    
URL url = f.toURI().toURL();
webEngine.load(url.toString());
```

But this shows the xml as an html, excluding the tags.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I used **JEditorPane** instead of WebView to show the XML tree, it works fine and it's so easy to implement